# In django, getting the following usernames in user profile

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i'm building a following model. I have created a following model as shown below and it is working fine in the admin. I did not create a view for the following because i'm in primary stage of building i'm testing in templates to bring that usernames in userspostlist, but it's not working.

my models.py for following:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user      = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
following = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='followed_by')


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.following.all().count())

class post(models.Model):
parent = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics', null=True, blank=True)
video = models.FileField(upload_to='post_videos', null=True, blank=True)
content = models.TextField()
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True)
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

objects = postManager()
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

my views.py for userpostlist:

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
model = post
template_name = 'blog/user_post.html'  #<app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
context_object_name = 'posts'


def get_queryset(self):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    return post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

and my userpostlist.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
  <h1 class="mb-3">posts by {{view.kwargs.username}}</h1>
  {% for user in username.owner.following.all %}
  {{ user.username }}
  {% endfor %}

    {% for post in posts %}
    <article class="content-section">
        <div class="article-metadata">
            <div class="img">
               <img class="rounded-circle article-img" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
            </div>

            <div class="profile-info">
              <a class="h2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
              <div class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</div>
            </div>
       </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Is there any problem with the userpostlist view in views.py? do i need to add some code there?

Comment: What's exactly not working?

Comment: i can't bring the following usernames in the template @Charnel

Comment: You didn't showed a `Post` model.

Comment: but i want to show the the following usernames in the postlist please helpme . Can i just show the post model here? @Charnel

Comment: You mean here? - `{% for user in username.owner.following.all %}
  {{ user.username }}
  {% endfor %}`

Comment: yes sir, exactly @Charnel

Comment: I do not see where are you passing `username` into context. Did you forgot to show some more related code?

Comment: No sir, i did not pass username into the context @Charnel

Comment: Then you can't use it in template. In general, in templates you can use only things that you explicitly pass there and things that are added automatically by Django (like the request object, depending on render method you're using).

Comment: how can i pass the username into the userpostlist's context , i"ve added the post model. please sir, help me @Charnel

Comment: One more question - in view you are filtering posts by author so I assume you want to show only one single author name, right?

Comment: Yes sir. @Charnel

Comment: Sir, this a user post list of individual users like how we see profile of other user. So i should see their following list. @Charnel

Answer (score 0):

You have some options here, where one is to pass users into context:

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['author'] = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username')
        return context
```

And then instead of this:

```
{% for user in username.owner.following.all %}
   {{ user.username }}
{% endfor %}
```

Use this:

```
{{ author.username }}
```

Comment: Sir, If i go to another users postlist like when we visit other users profile  i should see their followers i mean whom they are following..will it work that way. @Charnel

Comment: It will be something like `{% for follower in author.followed_by.all %} {{ follower.username }} {% endif %}`

Comment: Sir i did not use follower in the model. And also what is 'CarList'  that u use in the context. @Charnel

Comment: Corrected answer and also you do have a `related_name` for followers set as `followed_by`. `follower` itself is just a variable name inside the loop. You may chose any other.

Comment: I just have to add the  '' def get_context _data '' or i have to replace the whole. '' def get_query_set ''  in the user postlist view with the def get context data. @Charnel

Comment: Only add the `get_context_data`.

Comment: well i solve the context error but i'm not getting any data of the following usernames.. should i have to put the for loop inside the posts for loop@Charnel

Comment: No, you should get the user if you set it in context. Try to debug your view.

Comment: i should get for each particular users whom he following their usernames. @Charnel

Comment: so the problem is fixed..the problem was the whole `UserListView` function in views.py. @Charnel

Comment: It's great that you managed to solve it. Good luck with whatever you'll face next!

Comment: Thank u sir @Charnel